# arabxetex: how to write 'ayn with a long vowel fatha (dagger alif)

Tags: arabic, arabtex, arabxetex

With full vocalization turned on:

**a-l_`alamiyna** produces:

[image];

note that it messes up the *sukun* symbol on the *lam*

**a-l`aAlamiyna** produces:

[image]

**a-l'aalamiyna** produces a version that I think can be read correctly (but this is my first time ever taking a course in Arabic, so I could be wrong), but I mean, it doesn't feel like it has been written correctly in the ArabTeX romanization:

[image]

Is it possible to produce something like:

[image]

Alternatively, this question can be interpreted as: "what is the correct ArabTeX/ArabXeTeX romanization for *'alalameen*?"

Comment: Are you looking for the “dagger alif”? That’s produced with `_a`.

Comment: @Thérèse I am such a dummy! **a-l`a_alamiyna** is the right ArabTeX romanization to get the dagger alif with 'ayn. In terms of arabic though, is that pronounced the same way as **a-l'aalamiyna**?

Comment: Probably not a dummy, but just sleep-deprived like the rest of us ;-)  I’ll let a native speaker answer the question about pronunciation, because it’s been years since I’ve had reason to try pronouncing that.

Comment: @Thérèse Okay, no problem. I can probably ask my instructor anyway. Would you like to write up an answer? I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I won’t have time for a few days; you can write it if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the output below. This is the standard way for doing it. The picture you uploaded is not the standard notation especially the Sukoon and the little Alif. By the way, the picture is hand-written though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}

\setcode{utf8}

\<ٱلْعَالَمِينَ.  >

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
 
\begin{document}
\setarab
\fullvocalize
\arabtrue
\begin{RLtext}
al`_alamiyna
\end{RLtext}
\end{document}
```